Docker Registry Exit (0) immediately
I trying to learn kubernetes, minikube, and want so set up a local registry with Docker registry to be able to "pull an image" from a registry into minikube. I use VirtualBox version 7.0. The host is Windows 10 and the guest is Debian 12. On Debian I use Docker 27.2.0 and minikube v1.33.1. I "kind of" make it work with "insecure-registries":["192.168.54.177:5000", "localhost:5000"] in /etc/docker/daemon.json.
I have tried to set up a registry in Docker with image registry:2.7.0 using a username and password.
My main goal at this point is to set up the registry to need username and password so I can push a docker image to the registry.
Here is my setup

VirtualBox, version 7.0
Host OS: Windows 10
Guest OS: Debian 12
Docker, version 27.2.0
minikube, version v1.33.1
registry(dockerimage), version 2.7.0

I start registry with the folloing command.
docker container run \
-d \
-p 5000:5000 \
--entrypoint htpasswd \
--name registry \
-v /path/to/htpasswdfile:/home/max/auth/htpasswd \
-v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/home/max/auth/htpasswd" \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
registry:2.7.0 \
-Bbn max mypassword > /home/max/auth/htpasswd

Content in /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"experimental" : false
}

Log for the container that holds the registry.
max:<hash for my password>

docker ps -a results in the folloing
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMESdddc56870900   registry:2.7.0   "htpasswd -Bbn max m…"   8 minutes ago   Exited (0) 8 minutes ago             registry38ae724b1ccd   cfb4d9904335     "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   2 hours ago     Exited (2) 2 hours ago               musing_feynman

I have dried to follow instructions from stackoverflow, tutorials (both text and youtube) which has resulted in this mix of file content and commands.
Any help is appreciated. If you need more info, let me know and I'll do my best to provide.
